Getting data quality profile INVALID record counts for data quality rules from Informatica CDQ with APIs
I want to extract data quality profile results from Informatica CDQ via an API and get the row counts with ‘VALID’ and ‘INVALID’ values in the PrimaryRuleSet output for each rule configured in each profile.
I also need to get the threshold configured for each rule occurrence and corresponding column in the profile.
Can someone share the exact API calls and objects to get these values?
I've tried the Informatica documentation and some videos but can't find this info. I'm experimenting with various dq and frs APIs but haven't found the right APIs to get the actual row counts.
I can export via the user interface.
I've tried dqprofiling API and FRS API and can get rule set specifications, and the profile definition of columns + RuleSpec + dataset, but I haven't found the REST API to get the actual INVALID row counts.
I've tried documentation for the data profiling API:
https://docs.informatica.com/data-governance-and-quality-cloud/cloud-data-profiling/h2l/1547-getting-started-with-cloud-data-profiling-rest-api/getting-started-with-cloud-data-profiling-rest-api/overview.html
and a video walkthrough and Python code that doesn't have the API calls I'm looking for
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f__Awk694N0
